# How to replace the following types of quotes

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0

I have a function

```
string variable ="Multiply('a','b','c')*Add('a','b')"
```

While execution it has to be converted into 
    Multiply("a","b","c")*Add("a","b")

I tried in execution
     string variable1= "squre('a')"

```
 sb.AppendLine("return " + variable1.Replace("'", "\"") + ";");
```

it worked.

but when we have a mathematical operator it's not working.

Can some one suggest.

Comment: Why isn't working when there is a mathematical operator? Can you give an example? And have you declared the string properly with double qoutes and not as in question?

Comment: Hi Rmana,I just modified the question ,when there is a single varible it worked .But when there are multiple varibles seperated by comma  in side that function it dose not work.

Comment: It perfectly works for me. can you check again?

Comment: static void Main()
    {
                string variable ="Multiply('a','b','c')*Add('a','b')";
        
        Console.WriteLine(variable.Replace("'","\""));
    }